# How to remove team members from my Trello board as an Administrator

Tags: trello

I have read the answer to this question but my system isn't working that way.  I am an Administrator.  I have 2 Other members for this Board.  When I see the Board logging in as the Administrator, the the two members are not listed.  As an Administrator, I have several Boards.  When I look at a Board where there are three members (myself, and the other 2 members), I do not SEE the other 2 members -- neither on the left side (below my Board) or on the right side.  So to get rid of a member of a Board -- I'm not able to do it because I can't even see the other 2.

However, when my co-worker logs onto the system and accesses a Board where he is NOT the Administrator, he clearly sees in the upper right hand corner, the 3 members of this Board.  He has no permissions but he can see that I HAVE THE PERMISSIONS.

I have been working on this forever today and I am not seeing something so simple.  Please advise.

Comment: Is your sidebar hidden? http://blog.trello.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/sidebar-slide.gif

Comment: are the permissions for your board based on the organization instead of individuals? that _might_ explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the user you want to remove from the sidebar and then select from from board. I just tried so it should work. Good luck